# Login with test users fail when in sandbox mode (iOS SDK)

Tags: ios, facebook, sandbox, facebook-test-users

My problem is that if I have sandbox turned off for my iOS app I can log in to FB fine as one of my test users. But as soon as I enable sandbox I can no longer login. I get:

`-(void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled`

delegate method called.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I can however log in as a normal user when my app is set to sandbox. It seems something to do with being a test user.

Comment: Me too got stuck with the same issue . Any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue and I fixed it by just switching off sandbox mode and filled entries like bundle identifier in the facebook account where I registered my application.